# Which table is used for Foreign Exchange Rates in Apache OFBiz

Tags: database, ofbiz

Which table is used for Foreign Exchange Rates in `Apache OFBiz`?

[image: Foreign Exchange Rates]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entity/table you are looking for is named: UomConversionDated